# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS not recognizing wifi adapter after upgrade

Tags: drivers, 18.04, 20.04, iwlwifi

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 18 to ubuntu 20 on my Lenovo G500. Before the upgrade, I was able to use wifi easily with no setting up drivers. However, after upgrading to version 20, my laptop no longer recognizes the drivers and cannot use them.

I decided to use [Ubuntu's documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en) to help but still got nowhere.

When running `sudo lshw -C network` I get this output for the controller:

```bsh
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 135
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: c4
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:e0400000-e0401fff
```

When I run `lspci` (because I believe I have an internal wireless adapter) I get this output:

```bsh
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 135 (rev c4)
```

When I looked at the installed firmware, the correct firmware for the adapter was already installed `sudo ls /lib/firmware/`:

```bsh
....
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
...
```

I tried deleting that firmware and installing the a new copy from [Intel's driver site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html).
After I downloaded the new firmware, I pasted the new `iwlwifi-135-6.ucode` file into `/lib/firmware/` and rebooted my laptop. This did not solve the problem.

When running `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network | grep Kernal` has no output.

When I pull up the `Additional Drivers` GUI, it says that there are no additional drivers available.

I dont know much about this stuff but my thoughts are that the drivers are installed (given that they are present in `/lib/firmware`), but aren't being used (given the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network | grep Kernal`)

It is very important to me that we can find a solution to this. Please let me know if you need any more info!!!!

P.S. The ethernet (and bluetooth) does not work either which means I cannot use `apt-get`. My current process of getting outside files into the ubuntu machine is by downloading them on a separate machine and transferring them via flash drive.

System Info:

```
Linux user1 5.40-1068-gke #71-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 03:16:48 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edits requested by @chili555:

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

```bsh
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

`ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

```bsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Mar 15 23:15 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

`ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

```bsh
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

`sudo dkms status`

```bsh
sudo: dkms:command not found
```

`tail -n3 /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

```bsh
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

`sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

```
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1068-gke' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and finally: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 question has been updated with the requested information!

Comment: More, please: `sudo dkms status` and `tail -n3 /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` Thanks.

Comment: question has been updated! @chili555

Comment: Let's dig a bit deeper: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: @chili555 updated!

Comment: Solved by downloading this [package](https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-gke/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1068-gke_5.4.0-1068.71_amd64.deb) and then transferring it to my ubuntu machine. Then, moving that file to the desktop and running `sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb`